# Refund for a Nintendo switch game that does not work online after much effort

Tags: nintendo-switch, it-takes-two

Bought a game “it takes two” for Nintendo switch and it is unable to connect to the servers after much effort and troubleshooting. Tried everything to make it work but nothing works, hence why I want a refund. Is it possible ?

Comment: We are not Nintendo. We do not decide whether you can refund. [Contact Nintendo](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/assets/region_select.jsp?d=contactus&f=1), I'm sure they'd help you out :)

Comment: If you [edit] in what you have tried and what message(s) you receive when trying to connect, maybe we can help you solve that part of your problem :)